# How to achieve my custom post url structure?

Tags: url-rewriting, site-url

I have two CPTs for my anime site (Anime, Episode). When I add new Anime, url is `/anime/naruto/` and than I add new Episode for anime naruto but url is `/episode/title/`. I need structure like this: `/anime/naruto/episode/1/`. For explanation: `/anime/<name_of_anime>/episode/<number_of_episode>/`.

Is this url structure possible in wordpress? If yes, what functions I must use?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the custom URL using the function:

```
add_rewrite_rule($regex, $redirect, $after).
add_rewrite_rule(
           '^my-page/(.+)/?$',
           'index.php?pagename=my-page&url=$matches[1]',
           'top' );
```

You can write your own custom rewrite rule and redirect to appropriate page:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: And can u explain me how use this function for my problem? Same example please